# I want to see exact times of revisions

Tags: feature-request, editing

I want to see exact times of revisions. This may help to select the correct answer. There are 2 answers, but the helpful/key phrase/word in the older appears in revision which is 2 hours ago, and the newer is posted 2 hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mouseover the "2 hours ago", which will bring up the exact time and date of the post/revision/whatever:

[image: Mouseover example]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to reviewing the timestamps manually,  you can sort answers by date posted instead of by votes using the selector at the top of the answer section. This will sort by the exact date value even if the human readable value is rounded to the same number.